# Help with MySQL Queries to Analyze Hacked RockYou Password Data

Tags: sql, mysql, security, passwords

## Update #1

So I now have the data in the format shown in the screenshot below. The last thing I need to do is take this data and add a percentile column at the end. The percentile is valuable because it will show how common a given password is in the entire data set.

Does anyone have a good idea on a SQL query that will generate that percentile column?

[image]

## Original Post

I'm doing some analysis on the hacked "RockYou" password set for a research paper at my university. Long story short, RockYou is a service that allows users to create personalized MySpace widgets. The service was hacked, and the hacker released a giant text file of all of the plain text passwords, without any user information, to the public over a torrent.

I have imported all of the passwords into MySql, and I now have a giant table with 17004335 password records. I'd like to reform the data so I can quickly get the percentile of any provided password as well as the number of times the password occurs in the data set.

Here's what my current password table looks like:

```
password
password1
password2
password3
password1
password3
password3
```

I'd like to turn it into a simplified table that is ordered by occurrences descending. Also, I need some help correctly identifying what percentile any given password is in. Would **password3** be in the 100% percentile and **password1** be in the 33% percentile?

```
password    occurrences    percentile
password3   3              ?
password1   2              ?
password2   1              ?
```

I'm going to use this data to make a tool that will allow users to quickly see if a password occurs in the data set. The higher the percentile, the more insecure the password. Obviously, if the password is even in the data set that is a bad thing. =]

Any help with SQL queries to get this data reformed would be much appreciated.

Comment: But seriously, I'd be interested in seeing the analysis. Is this going to be public in some form?

Comment: Yeah I'll post the tool online for everyone to use freely.

Comment: I think your use of percentile is wrong. Percentile applies when you have sortable values, such as age of persons in a group, oldest person is in the uppermost percentile. So then percentile value can answer some useful questions, such as "what is the median age of group?" or "what is the chance that randomly sampled person will be aged X or less?" What useful answers would percentile yield in this case? I think what you should be looking at is frequency as it would allow you ask questions like "If attacker is manually guessing passwords, what chance he has to succeed before lockout?"

Comment: @Konrads Updated my post and responded to your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this might help get you started:

```
select
 password,
 count(*) as freq,
 if(t.total = 0, 0, (count(*)/t.total) * 100) as pct_freq
from
 passwords 
join (
  select count(*) as total from passwords
) t 
group by
 password
order by
 freq desc limit 100;
```

Personally, I'd be looking at doing this outside of MySQL in C# or whatever. Parse the password file and use a data structure like a Dictionary/Hashtable to tally the data...